# Which possessive pronouns should I use in "I'm not a person who..."?

Tags: relative-clauses

Consider this sentence, please:

> **I**'m not a person **who** screams out **my** achievements from the rooftops.

Why do we use "**my**" instead of "**his/her**" in the sentence above, when "**I**" is **not** the antecedent of "**who**", the subject of the relative clause?

Comment: What leads you to think that *I* is not the antecedent of *who*? What if the sentence were the following: *I am not a person who sleeps.* What do you think the antecedent of *who* would be? (1) "Are you a person who sleeps?" (1) "No, I am not." (2) "Who sleeps?" "Not I."

Comment: The idiomatic phrase is [**shout from the rooftops**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shout+from+the+rooftops).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context, *his* or *her* or *their* could refer to someone other than *I*.

> I'm not a person who screams out his achievements from the rooftops. I
> just believe President Trump is due some credit.
>
> I'm not a person who screams out her achievements from the rooftops.
> I'm just a quietly supportive parent to my daughter.
>
> I'm not a person who screams out their achievements from the rooftops. Those guys get enough publicity as it is in any case.

The use of *my* makes clear that the speaker is referring to their own achievements thereby removing any ambiguity that could arise.

Comment: As you suggest, a sentence like this implies a contrast: either with the speaker shouting something else, someone else shouting the speaker's achievements (e.g. the speaker's mother), or other people shouting their own achievements. The choice of pronoun will depend on the contrast.